# Re-IPing a Windows 2012 r2 Domain Controllers

Tags: ip, active-directory, domain, windows-server-2012

We are moving to a new IP range (not private IPs). I am trying to find a checklist on re-IPing Domain Controllers(DCs are our DNSs). No experience with re-IPing DCs, but have read that it is not something you want to do if you don't have to. I have only found a couple things, but those articles made it seem not as complicated as I have heard. I have not seen if it matters on if the primary or secondary DC is re-IP'd first.

Hopefully someone has some experience and might have some dos and don'ts.

I appreciate the help.

Comment: If you do find one, I imagine it would be fairly short, since nothing in AD relies on fixed IP addresses (unless the domain admin actively goes out of their way to make it so) – everything uses DNS.

Comment: There is no problem with changing IPs. You just need to make sure the DHCP Server hands out new DNS server IP addresses to the workstations.